# Is there a search equivalent to "NOT IN"?

Tags: feature-request, search

I would like to obtain posts that are `NOT IN` the search results of an initial search, working similarly to the manner in which `NOT IN` is used in SQL.

Currently, the search can only return all the posts that I *don't* want to identify, not the results I want to identify.

The reason I want this feature is to help clean up a beta Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is undocumented, many of the [google tips & tricks](http://www.google.com/intl/en/insidesearch/tipstricks/all.html#characters) work with the standard SO search.

For instance, let's say I want to [search for all question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion), I get 5.9 million results.

There are [500k questions with the word 'test' in them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+test), but I don't want those questions.

So I [search for `is:question -test`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+-test) and get 5.4 million results.

The ones I know and use are:

- `-` to exclude words
- `5..6` to designate a range (or `..5` for less than, or `5..` for more than)